# Using update Query for updating multiple rows with calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables a "`product`" table

```
**prod_cat**     **prod_code**    **prod_name**   **prod_desc** **prod_price** **prod_stock**
```

MB01       MB01_micro   ASU M5A_M      Asus         mobo      7500       [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If5v6.png)45

PRO01     PRO01_01     INT_i3_7300 Intel core i3  Processor  9313        5

and another table "`cart`" table

```
id cart_cust_id  cart_prod_id  cart_qty cart_prod_total cart_status
1   xxxx            ASU M5A_M     1        7500            NOT PAID
2   xxxx            INT_i3_7300   2        18626           NOT PAID
```

What I need is a query or a procedure to reduce the "`prod_stock`" according to the value in "`cart_qty`". Any suggestions ?

I have also provided the screenshots of the 2 tables in the links.[Screen shots of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVh51.png)

My update statement:

```
UPDATE product 
  SET prod_stock = ((SELECT cart_quantity 
                     FROM cart 
                     WHERE prod_code LIKE cart_prod_id 
                       AND cart_cust_id LIKE 'Gireesh.R.Pai@gmail.com' 
                       AND cart_status LIKE 'NOT PAID') - prod_stock)
```

Gives an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: tag the DBMS which you are using.

Comment: and show what have you tried to do (something about UPDATE command...)

Comment: I'm sorry . It didnt allow me to upload image directly. Im now to this so . Im sorry about the mistakes.

Comment: what i tried 

UPDATE product SET prod_stock = ((SELECT cart_quantity FROM cart WHERE prod_code LIKE cart_prod_id AND cart_cust_id LIKE 'Gireesh.R.Pai@gmail.com' AND cart_status LIKE 'NOT PAID')- prod_stock)

Comment: Im using SQL Server 2012 by the way and the query i tired gave me this error 

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Have you ever tried to give a look at (eg.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables and

```
 ;WITH T AS(
    Select * FROM Product P 
    INNER JOIN CART C ON C.cart_prod_id = P.prod_code
    )
    Update T SET prod_stock = prod_stock - cart_quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

With no tempdb use (faster way) :

```
UPDATE P
SET
    P.prod_stock = P.prod_stock - C.cart_quantity
FROM
    Product AS P
    INNER JOIN CART AS C ON (C.cart_prod_id = P.prod_code)
```

You can add a WHERE clause :

```
UPDATE P
SET
    P.prod_stock = P.prod_stock - C.cart_quantity
FROM
    Product AS P
    INNER JOIN CART AS C ON (C.cart_prod_id = P.prod_code)
WHERE *XXX* = *YYY* AND ...
```